# Could not resolve host: rest-proxy when I add a new avro consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

knowing that my kafka_cluster work fine and I'm using docker-compose
I put inside the container :registery schema

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v1+json" \
    --data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "avro", "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}' \
    http://rest-proxy:8082/consumers/my_avro_consumer
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rest-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

`rest-proxy:8082`

This must be an actual server or IP address.

To make it work with a short-name, setup your DNS server to know that you have a machine with a hostname of `rest-proxy` exists on your network.

> I'm using docker-compose

Make sure that your `curl` is happening within the Docker network.

For example,

`docker-compose exec kafka-rest sh`, and run `curl` from there